# Trying to do an update on Android Studio app using PHP file

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying an update query on an Android app using a `PHP` file to update the XAMPP database. I have a page where someone can edit their profile after they have registered and logged into the app. I'm using `$_SESSION` to get the `user_id` when someone logs in. I'm basically using the same code for the register `PHP` file and for the edit profile `PHP` file except the `SQL` query is different. The Edit Profile works when I run it on localhost but not on my Android app. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks.

register.php

```
<?php
$error = NULL;
include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['txtName']) && isset($_POST['txtGender']) && isset($_POST['txtPassword']) && isset($_POST['txtUsername'])){
    $name = $_POST['txtName'];
    $gender = $_POST['txtGender'];
    $username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `user`(`name`, `gender`,`username`, `password`) VALUES ('$name','$gender','$username','$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    if($name == $error || $gender == $error || $username == $error || $password == $error){
        echo "Insert Failed";
    }
    elseif($result > 0){
        if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){
            echo "success";
            exit;
        }
        echo "Insert Successfully";
    //  // header("location: login.php");
    }
    else{
        if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){
            echo "Registration Failed";
            exit;
        }
        echo "Insert Failed";
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insert Register</h1>
<form action="<?PHP $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="txtName" value="" /> <br/>
    Gender <input type="text" name="txtGender" value="" /> <br/>    
    Username <input type="text" name="txtUsername" value="" /> <br/>
    Password <input type="password" name="txtPassword" value=""/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Insert"/> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

editprofile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$error = NULL;
include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['txtName']) && isset($_POST['txtGender']) && isset($_POST['txtPassword']) && isset($_POST['txtUsername'])){
    $name = $_POST['txtName'];
    $gender = $_POST['txtGender'];
    $username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];


    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];


    $query = "UPDATE `user` SET `name`= '$name',`gender`= '$gender',`username`= '$username',`password`= '$password' WHERE `user_id' = '$user_id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    if($name == $error || $gender == $error || $username == $error || $password == $error){
        echo "Insert Failed";
    }
    elseif($result > 0){
        if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){
            echo "success";
            exit;
        }
        echo "Insert Successfully";
    //  // header("location: login.php");
    }
    else{
        if(isset($_POST['mobile']) && $_POST['mobile'] == "android"){
            echo "Registration Failed";
            exit;
        }
        echo "Insert Failed";
    }
}

?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insert Edit Profile</h1>
<form action="<?PHP $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="txtName" value="" /> <br/>
    Gender <input type="text" name="txtGender" value="" /> <br/>    
    Username <input type="text" name="txtUsername" value="" /> <br/>
    Password <input type="password" name="txtPassword" value=""/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Insert"/> </form>

<?php
    echo $user_id;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any input named `mobile`.

Comment: mobile and android are inputs in the Android app